# Adicionar Class DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, css, razor

Como eu insiro a @class = "form-control" no código abaixo?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="disabledSelect" class="control-label col-md-2">Status:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.Status, new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Ativo", Text = "Ativo" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Inativo", Text = "Inativo" },
            }, @Model.Status, @Model.Status)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Porque o `@Model.Status` repete duas vezes no final?

Answer (score 1):

No meu caso uso da seguinte maneira.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Department, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Depts, "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "departmentList", @class = "form-control" })
```

No seu caso fica dessa forma

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.Status, new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Value = "Ativo", Text = "Ativo" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "Inativo", Text = "Inativo" },
}, @Model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "isActive", @class = "form-control" })
```